# Is it possible to load XAML runtime in Avalonia

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avaloniaui

In WPF it is possible to load XAML at runtime and put it in a ContentControl using XamlReader.Load()

Is this possible in Avalonia?

I want to get to a point where I have a user control that contains a content control and based on my configuration, this could point to a file on disk having XAML code to read.

In WPF this works nicely, and the XAML is imported, parsed and the datacontext is inherited, allowing my to put data inside the loaded XAML through my databindings.

I have been searching for an equivalent in Avalonia, but not been successfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.Loader` package and use AvaloniaRuntimeXamlLoader class.

Comment: Cool... can I find any good examples anywhere? I am brand new to Avalonia.. but experienced in WPF. But working on a small project that needs to be portable...

Comment: @Hans-HenrikMøller the best examples we have can probably be found in our unit tests: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/tests/Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.UnitTests/Xaml/BasicTests.cs for example

Comment: An extension to this question... it does not load merged dictionaries? or am I doing something wrong?